# Retain main logo file while generating scale files in UWP apps

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I have UWP app and in the package manifest file designer I am providing a source path of my package logo and generate the scale files. This works fine but the original app logo file (applogo.png) is not present in the assets folder. If I force copy the original file based on which the scale files were generated, the scale files break. And if I try to manually select the scale files, it asks to delete the original file. Is there any way we can retain the original logo file (applogo.png) along with the scale files.

Adding screens below:

**Step 1: Added Package logo and generated the scale files**
[image]

**Verify scale files**

[image]

**Step 2: Copying the original file at the same location. This breaks the scale files path.**
[image]

**Step 3: Manually select the missing scale file. This will ask for deleting the original file and I want to retain the original file as well.**

[image]

Appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you put your original image which has the same name with the generated scale files in the same directory, it may affect the match operation.

So you can change the name of your original file(e.g. applogo.png -> myAppLogo.png) if you still want to put original file and generated scale files in the same directory. Or put the file in a different folder(e.g. Assets folder -> MySourceImage folder -> applogo.png).

Comment: Thanks Faywang, the issue is that the package manifest file references the original file name and not scaled one and still removes the original file.

Comment: When you use the above method, will the original logo file and the scale files exists in the project? About "the issue is that the package manifest file references the original file name and not scaled one and still removes the original file.", Do you mean you only put the original file in manifest and use its name, but still ask you to remove the original file? Can you describe it in more detail and What is your behavior?